# Multiple Content Types with overlapping Column Names

Tags: sharepoint

I have two InfoPath form based content types with overlapping column names. Can I assign these two content types to single list?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although depending on what you want to do there is some potential for confusion over field IDs if you don't have everything set up as site columns/content types - A shared name won't necessarily be enough to get the data from both forms into the same column.